# How do you slice arrays in D?

Tags: arrays, d

How are arrays manipulated in D?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/arrays.html) you can find a complete reference of array manipulations in D.

Answer (score 3):

To slice arrays, it's a simple matter of using

```
int[7] a;
int[] b;
b = a[5..7];
```

which sets b[0] to a[5] and b[1] to a[6].  But remember that this is a reference to the elements in a, *not* another copy of them.  If you change b[0], this also affects a[5].

If you want to copy, you have to do:

```
int[7] a;
int[2] b;
b[0..1] = a[5..7];
```

This is because b is a static array; in the first code block, it was dynamic (effectively a pointer to somewhere within another array).

Answer (score 3):

FYI. You can also copy with:

```
int[7] a;
int[] b;
b = a[5..7].dup;
```